# Wix Upgrade MSI from Per-Machine to Per-user

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

i am trying to Upgrade MSI from Per-Machine to Per-User.. but its not working.
After Upgrade it shows twice on Control panel and twice shortcut on the desktop means its unable to uninstall pervious one.

and it able to Upgrade Per-Machine to Per-machine and Per-User to Per-User but unable to upgrade Per-Machine to Per-user

New Build Code
[image]

OLD BUILD CODE
[image]

Comment: I think the preferable way to share code is as text.  Images makes it very difficult to try and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the major upgrade does not work across installation contexts (what WiX calls installScope). Thus the previous version is not being uninstalled. The second note on [Major Upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786) says this:

> **Note**  If an application is installed in the per-user [installation context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd765197), any major upgrade to the application must also be performed using the per-user context. If an application is installed in the per-machine installation context, any major upgrade to the application must also be performed using the per-machine context. The Windows Installer will not install major upgrades across installation context.